# Creating VMs without public IP in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, private-subnet, google-vpc

Any way to restrict `external(Public) IP` in `GCP` at `Subnet` . It seems if we want to create a `VM` without an `external IP`, we have to select `External IP- None`  during `VM` creation. Can't we set `External IP- None` at Subnet configuration and any host created in this subnet will not be having a `public/external IP`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up an organization policy constraint in order to [define allowed external IPs for VM instances](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints#constraints-supported-by-multiple-google-cloud-services). With this constraint your could restrict configuration of external IPs to a list of instances. Leaving the `allowedValues` list empty will make no longer possible the configuration of external IP addresses to VMs within the organization projects. Find all the relevant information on the following section of the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#disableexternalip).

If you find the policy constraint approach to be too restrictive (notice that [many other products that rely on VMs will be affected](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#best_practices)) another strategy that you could set in place would be to automate the deployments of VMs with the [gcloud compute instances create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create) command and take advantage of the [--no-address](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create#--no-address) flag in order to avoid assigning external IP addresses to the instances.

Comment: Daniel’s answer is correct. +If you want to follow the implementation using a visual approach. Watch this video on [How to limit public IPs on Google Cloud](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SiZ5b4a4EUY)

Answer (score 1):

For those who are looking for a per-instance solution using Google's GCP REST API, just be sure there's no `accessConfigs` in your `networkInterfaces` section of your request's JSON body:

```
        "machineType": "zones/{my_zone}/machineTypes/{my_machine_type}",
        "name": "my_instance_name",
        "networkInterfaces": [{
            "network": "my_vpc_network_ref",
            "subnetwork": "my_subnet_ref"
            # Don't include these commented lines if you only want a private IP 
            # "accessConfigs": [{
            #     "name": "External NAT",
            #     "type": "ONE_TO_ONE_NAT"
            # }]
        }],
```

All the parts starting with "my" are placeholders/variables.

I realize the actual question was about how to do this at the subnet level, and the answers provided help do this at the Organization or Project level, but the title of the question didn't specify what level we forbade private IPs, and it's not clear from the GCP documentation what the equivalent REST API call is for the `--no-address` flag, so I wanted to document it here for future coders.